# C++ Partial template specialization on virtual method

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I have a simple base class Shape with its derived class Ball. The aim is to have genericity on the scalar type and dimensions hence the use of templates.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>

template<typename T, std::size_t DIM>
class Shape {
public:
    Shape(std::array<T,DIM> base_point) : base_point_(base_point) {}
    virtual T volume() const = 0;
protected:
    std::array<T,DIM> base_point_;
};

template<typename T, std::size_t DIM>
class Ball : public Shape<T,DIM> {
public:
    Ball(std::array<T,DIM> base_point, T radius) : Shape<T,DIM>(base_point), radius_(radius) {}
    virtual T volume() const;
private:
    T radius_;
};

// Cannot use the generic code below because of Template may not be 'virtual' ?
// template<typename T>
// T Ball<T,2>::volume() const { return M_PI * radius_ * radius_; }

template<>
float Ball<float,2>::volume() const { return M_PI * radius_ * radius_; }

// template<typename T>
// T Ball<T,3>::volume() const { return 4/3 * M_PI * radius_ * radius_ * radius_; }

template<>
float Ball<float,3>::volume() const { return 4/3 * M_PI * radius_ * radius_ * radius_; }

int main() {
    Ball<float,2> circle{{0.2f,0.3f}, 4.0f};
    std::cout << circle.volume() << std::endl;
}
```

I would like to use partial template specialization in order to compute the volume depending on the dimension. The code works but is cumbersome if I have to specialize for another type such as double (code would be the same).

I know that I cannot have partial template specialization for virtual methods but when I use the commented code above I have the following errors instead of *Error : Template may not be 'virtual'* :

```
shape_generic_naive.cpp:24:25: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Sphere<T, 2ul>’
 T Sphere<T,2>::volume() const {return M_PI * radius_ * radius_; }
                         ^
shape_generic_naive.cpp:15:7: error: declaration of ‘class Sphere<T, 2ul>’
 class Sphere : public Shape<T,DIM> {
```

I do not really get this error, how to avoid it and what are ways to get this genericity elegantly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly always, if you need function template partial specialisation, you can use the "delegate to class" trick:

```
template <class T, std::size_t DIM>
struct BallVolume;

template <class T>
struct BallVolume<T, 2>
{
  static T compute(T radius) { return M_PI * radius * radius; }
};

template <class T>
struct BallVolume<T, 3>
{
  static T compute(T radius) { return 4.0/3.0 * M_PI * radius * radius * radius; }
};


template<typename T, std::size_t DIM>
class Ball : public Shape<T,DIM> {
public:
    Ball(std::array<T,DIM> base_point, T radius) : Shape<T,DIM>(base_point), radius_(radius) {}
    virtual T volume() const { return BallVolume<T, DIM>::compute(radius_); }
private:
    T radius_;
};
```

Notice that your formula for 3D volume was incorrect: `4/3` is `1`, as it's integer division.

Also, to keep it really type-neutral, you should cast the constants to `T`:

```
return static_cast<T>(M_PI) * radius * radius;
return 4 / static_cast<T>(3.0) * static_cast<T>(M_PI) * radius * radius * radius;
```

Comment: `BallVolume` should be declared before `Ball`, or the `volume` member function defined later

Comment: @PiotrS. Or the reader apply common sense when reading the answer. I didn't `#include` the header for `std::size_t` either. But just in case, I reversed the order.

Comment: Thank you it works fine for me ! I indeed used my common sense at first read ;). edit : why would the static_cast<T> be needed on the 3.0 ? 4.0/3.0 is not sure enough ?

Comment: @coincoin `4.0` is of type `double`. If you instantiate it with `T = float`, you can get a (justified) compiler warning.

Comment: Ok thank you for the enlightments ! Just a last question. Why do I still have this error (invalid use of incomplete type...) : I have just implemented an alternative way with static polymorphism using CRTP  in order to avoid virtual call and I have the exact same errors if I uncomment my original code. Using your trick also work in this context but my comment code should work now since there is not virtual template specialization with CRTP ! If needed I can post the code or ask another question.

Comment: @coincoin That really looks like a separate question. But consider the fact that you're trying to partially specialise the function template `Ball::volume`, and partial specialisation of function templates is not allowed.

Comment: Oh I see thank you for your point : only full function template specialization is allowed. I will stick with your solution then.